# How to fix the errore bound in julia?

Tags: julia

This code is a part of a code which sort nondominated points. `F` is a cell array that keeps the pareto fronts. but Julia gives this error:

`BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{Any,1} at index [1]
setindex!(::Array{Any,1}, ::Any, ::Int64) at essentials.jl:183
macro expansion at Nondominated sorting.juliarc.jl:41 [inlined]`

would you please help me. How can I fix it?

```
#=pop is a structure including 
struct individual
    position
    cost
    Rank
    Dominationset
    Dominatedcount
    Crowdingdostance
end
this pop is used for this code as input
5-element Array{individual,1}:
 individual(Any[-3, 4, -2], Any[1.0, 1.0], Any[], Any[], Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[4, 4, 1], Any[1.0, 1.0], Any[], Any[], Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[1, 4, 4], Any[1.0, 1.0], Any[], Any[], Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[4, 4, -2], Any[1.0, 1.0], Any[], Any[], Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[1, 4, 2], Any[0.999999, 1.0], Any[], Any[], Any[], Any[])=#

using JuMP,DataStructures
npop=length(pop);
l=0;
F=[]; # F{1}=[] in matlab it is correct
for i=1:npop
    for j=i+1:npop
        p=pop[i];
        q=pop[j];
        if (dominates(p.cost,q.cost))
            append!(p.Dominationset,j);
            append!(q.Dominatedcount,l+1)
        end
        if (dominates(q.cost,p.cost))
            append!(q.Dominationset,i);
            append!(p.Dominatedcount,l+1)
        end
        pop[i]=p;
        pop[j]=q;
    end
    if pop[i].Dominatedcount==[]
        F[1]=[F;i]; #F{1}=[F{1} i] in matlab is used
        append!(pop[i].Rank,1);
    end
end
```

the dominates function is as following:

```
function dominates(x,y)  
    b=all(x.<=y) && any(x.<y);
    return(b);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
F[1]=[F;i]
```

`F` is an empty vector, so you cannot assign anything to element `1`. This is different from Matlab, which automatically (and imho, dangerously) dynamically extends your array. Instead use: `push!`:

```
push!(F, ??)
```

I put in the questionmarks because I don't understand what you are actually trying to put into F here. Putting `F` itself inside a vector, and *then* assigning that to the first element of `F`? This makes noe sense to me, sorry to say. (**Edit:** Your Matlab code, `F{1}=[F{1} i]`, makes no sense here, either. Did you by any chance mean to write `F = [F, i]`?)

Also, are you sure you need to use `Any` everywhere? Untyped `struct`s and `Any` vectors will make your code extremely slow.

Comment: Thanks very much. In fact `F` is a matrix that any element  is a vector or matrix of the some scalers. for example, after running this code. F must be as follow:
    `F=[[43;74;21]]
   3-element Array{Array{Int64,N} where N,1}:
   [43, 74, 21]`

Comment: That doesn't seem right: `[[43;74;21]]`is *not* a 3-element vector, but a 1-element vector, which contains a 3-element vector. Are you correctly copy-pasting this from the command line?

Comment: Also, are you saying that `F` should be a vector of vectors? Or a vector of matrices, or a vector of a mix of both vectors and matrices? Are all these arrays of the same size and shape?

Comment: yes. Im sorry . It was wrong. it has one vector as bellow. but in other section of the main code some others will add to F. then as whole, F is n dimensional that every it's element is array. as well as, these arrays have different size. but shapes can be same.

Comment: Anyway, just use `push!`, and if you care about performance, see if you can assign concrete types to your struct field, or at least avoid all the `Any`-vectors.

Comment: Sure. I am really grateful for your helps.

Comment: If you don't mind, would you please say me why `F` has unwanted element.
what is the first element?
`F
4-element Array{Any,1}:
  Any[Any[#= circular reference @-1 =#], 1, 2, 5]
 1
 2
 5`

Comment: it is the same code but pop was produced randomly and instead of `F[1]=[F;i]` used `F[1]=push!(F,i)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193327/discussion-between-somayeh-esmaeili-and-dnf).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found my wrong. I should only use `push!(F,i)` not `F[1]=push!(F,i)`.:)